# Weird response when trying to connect to localhost:4567 in a secure spark-java app

Tags: security, ssl

I'm developing a REST API using the last version of spark-java (2.9.1). The project has a static page (index.html) that interacts throught the REST API and loads some data to the page using typescript. Recently I added security by calling 'secure()'. The fact is that the page in **https://localhost:4567** is working **fine** but if I try to load **http://localhost:4567** I see that the server sends some binary data that looks awful in the navigator.

This is what I do reproduce the problem:

edu@Edu-HP:$ curl -i http://localhost:4567 >ppp

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100    14    0    14    0     0   3500      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3500

edu@Edu-HP:$ hd ppp

00000000  15 03 03 00 02 02 50                              |......P|

00000007

Note that the output that is generated consists on 6 binary bytes. I don't know if it's working as expected or if there is any problem with the framework. I expected to see some http error code, perhaps I'm wrong.. If you try it on the navigator you will see some strange characters..

I enabled jetty log and what I see is that the following exception is thrown:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

I imagine that is normal, but please tell me if there is any exception that I'm not catching..

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing an HTTPS site using a HTTP request. Usually one TCP port only provides a plain text HTTP or a SSL/TLS encrypted site at a time, not both at the same time.

In general it would be possible on server-side to check the first received data and check if it is an HTTP request or an SSL/TLS handshake and automatically switch to the correct protocol, but such an implementation in an HTTP(S) server if very uncommon.

In your case the error is caused by the following problem: 
The client sends the plain text HTTP request but the server expects the CLIENT_HELLO from the SSL/TLS handshake. Therefore it answers with some binary data - most likely the SSL/TLS alert message that invalid data has been received.

Conclusion:

When talking to an HTTPS server use the HTTPS protocol, even if it runs on localhost. If you want to test it without HTTPS use the HTTP port instead (depending on the server configuration you may need to add an plain text HTTP port if by default only an HTTPS port is opened).

Comment: Hi Robert, I understand what you say, but how can avoid the situation where the user types http instead of https. Is it possible by software or is it a matter of hardware settings?

Comment: @EduardoSabaj If the user types http than the web browser has to respect this (see also my updated answer). But in my experience most users don't type anything in the address bar as long as they are not forced to do so. Hence the easiest workaround is to provide a clickable link e.g. in an HTML file and everything is fine.